# How to open an attachment URL within Salesforce1 app?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, mobile

I am trying to create a UI design where a button click would open up a record's attached pdf file. Although I am able to do this using javascript as follows:

```
var attachmentUrl = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P200034NC9k';    
window.open(attachmentUrl)
```

but it opens as a downloadable file in mobile. I need to use the built-in salesforce preview to show this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to open the PDF within salesforce1 mobile using a hyperlink to the record instead of the attachment file. When you click on the link, the attachment would open up within the app instead of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that a PDF or any other attachment will need to be downloaded to the mobile device in some form for it to be viewed by a user. You're not going to be able to "render" an existing PDF as a visualforce mobile page for someone to view it on a mobile device. A user will have to download the PDF if they want to view it.

I wasn't aware that SF1 Mobile had a built-in PDF viewer, but I've not kept up with the latest versions/iterations. In the past, SF has always left that to the mobile device to handle using other apps, but that may have changed and I simply missed it as I don't use the mobile app very often.

Comment: When you go to the Files tab within your salesforce1 app and select on any pdf file you may have uploaded, it would open up within the app itself. So I am trying to find a way to do the same but with a button click on my page.

Comment: If that's the case, that would seem to require you to connect into the API so you can use the same kind of call that makes the file association for the device with the SF1 mobile app.